# Separate tables vs. one big one in Azure table storage (NoSQL)

Tags: database, azure, database-design, nosql

I'm using Azure Tables and I'm trying to figure out how I should organize my data.

Each entity in a table has a PartitionKey and a RowKey and my understanding is that partitions should be used to organize similar objects for scalability. In the example on the site they used movie entities where the category (action, sci fi, etc) is the PartitionKey while the title (fast and the furious, etc.) is the RowKey.

Going with the above example, lets say we have no duplicate movies and you also wanted to keep track of each particular movies rental history, i.e location, due date, customer, etc.

Would it be bad practice to have one table to store all of this and use a separate partition for the rental entities? To be clear, I'm talking about a movie item and its corresponding history items together in the same denormalized table in separate partitions.

Would there be an advantage to using two separate tables and if not, then what is the point of tables?

EDIT:

PartitionKey|  RowKey  |   prop0   |   prop1   |...

------------------------------------------------...

SciFi           | StarWars| foo0: bar0 | foo1: bar1|...

Rental         | StarWars| foo0: bar0 | foo1: bar1|...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the notion of table storage is that you can "dump" large amounts of data knowing that search facilities are very poor, you won't be able to issue SQL queries, hence no RDBMS and that it is a means of storing much data.
Indeed, partitionKey and rowKey are the only indexed columns you get with Azure storage, this means that searching by partitionKey or rowKey will be quicker than searching by any other column. If you need to retrieve data swiftly then blob storage or table storage is a no-go. If you just want to keep a record for audit purposes or history purposes then yes.
However, if you want to use it in a video store for instance and need to retrieve client's details, then as I mentioned it's bad practice. You'd better of using RDBMS. Lastly, you can't do JOIN or other RDBMS queries etc in table storage i.e. between two tables.

Comment: my boss wants to use nosql for schemaless qualities, that is not the question. The question is should movie and rentals be separate tables? by using different partitions I think the same thing will be accomplished

Comment: I would say it's bad practice having 2 different notions if you like, on the same table i.e. rented movies and existing movies. Using the Partition key and Row key for indexing is definitely the way to go, but you don't want to have mixed up concepts. The tables are still tables and still describe a set of data, like in any other database (sql, mysql etc). What doesn't is blob storage which acts more like a hard disk space.

Comment: Plus, should you decide in the future to add one extra column for a purpose in the rented section, it will be inherited by the "to rent" section, and vice versa.